# TinyMce 3.5 disable cleanup

Tags: tinymce

After editing the content using the html window, tinymce removes some html content. Is there any way to disable the cleanup method in tinymce 3.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this feature has been removed since tinymce version 3.4. See the [tinymce docs](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3acleanup) for more information. If there is code that should not get stripped out of the editor you will need to adjust your editor settings valid_elements and valid_children.

Comment: I need to keep the html, head, body, title and meta tags and even doctype tags. Can you give me some examples? Thank you

Comment: you cannot keep those tags, because a tinymce editor is inside a contenteditable iframe which has its own tags already

Comment: you may load those tags or better the content of those tags to the tinymce editor iframe